# DC2type on greenDao

Tags: android, arrays, json, greendao

I am using GreenDao for Android application, with some specification,  for example, I have a Contact Model with some information like name, avatar, phone number, etc...

Right now the need is to change from only one phone number to a multiphone number.

Instead of creating two tables (table for numbers, and table for contacts), I really need just one information is the number so in my backend the contact numbers is stocked on a DC2type, (a  json array saved as a string).

Do we have a possibility to do that using GreenDao?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i search for a solution or a DC2type implementation , etc ... and nothing is found

so i decide to created by my self , and this is what i did : 
using the @Convert annotation presented of GreenDao 3 :

```
@Property(nameInDb = "phoneNumbers")
@Convert(converter = PhoneNumbersConverter.class, columnType = String.class)
private List<String> phoneNumbers;

static class PhoneNumbersConverter implements PropertyConverter<List<String>, String> {
    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityProperty(String databaseValue) {
        List<String> listOfStrings = new Gson().fromJson(databaseValue,List.class);
        return listOfStrings;
    }
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseValue(List<String> entityProperty) {
        String json = new Gson().toJson(entityProperty);
        return json;
    }
}
```

short story long ,  i create a  json to array parser
thanks to myself to helped me  :D